# JSON Parsing App Crashing

Tags: android, json

Im trying to parse a JSON url through this code and it is crashing everytime i try to run this application.
In main activity im calling ServiceHandler class which is available on internet for fetching string from JSON Url's.

```
package com.example.parseable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static String strurl=***;   /**url cannot be disclosed, JSON on url is=[{"Pan_Number":"PV2398P","UserName":"DIVYA  VERMA","RMContactNumber":"77867651"}] **/



    JSONArray ja;

    String pan;
    String name;
    String rm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        TextView panno=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.panx);
        TextView uname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.namex);
        TextView rmno=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.rmx);

        ServiceHandler sh=new ServiceHandler();

        String jsonstr=sh.makeServiceCall(strurl, ServiceHandler.GET);

        if(jsonstr!=null){
            try{
                ja=new JSONArray(jsonstr);

                JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(0);

                pan=jo.getString("Pan_Number");
                name=jo.getString("UserName");
                rm=jo.getString("RMContactNumber");




            } catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the specified url");
        }

        panno.setText(pan);
        uname.setText(name);
        rmno.setText(rm);

    }


}


and ServiceHandler Class

package com.example.parseable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: See your logcat to see `NetworkOnMainThreadException` or any other problem. Include the stacktrace in your questions.

Comment: thanx @laalto, i got it.. i have to execute it in a separate thread. Now, i did it using AsyncTask.. worked...